# Mimicking/faking svn:externals using TFS

Tags: svn, tfs, svn-externals, externals

I have multipile projects, each of which references the same library project.  I want to be able to make changes to the library to support one of those projects without having to support those same changes in all of my projects.  In SVN, all I had to do was set up an external that would check out a particular revision of the library and any further changes after that revision would never get pulled in unless I explicitly decided to change the revision of the library I check out.  I understand from other posts that the concept of externals is not explicitly supported in TFS, but Bart Wullems posted something on his blog suggesting that it might be possible to simulate this behavior using Project Linker (http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2010/08/simulating-svn-externals-feature-in-tfs.html).

Does anyone know of a good way to simulate this aspect of svn:externals when using TFS?

Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify, The folks over at Microsoft seem to think that branching the shared library at the version that you want, then checking that code out is the "proper" way to do this. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/tfsversioncontrol/thread/96AD1D57-69D3-4BF2-9E05-B151A338AB8F

However, I would still be interested in hearing if anyone has a good way to simulate this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view, the externals concept is svn is somehow similar to the concept of workspace definition in TFS. In TFS, by defining a new workspace, you can determine which version of libraries or projects to be checked out when getting the last version of your desired.